# modifying a user model with a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

total rails noob here so bear with me. I've been stuck for a long time trying to figure out how to make a page that allows a logged-in user to change, via text field, certain attributes of the user model. For instance, my user model has a number of "measurement" attributes that i'd like to directly modify via the page. My user model is running on Devise--I'm not sure if i'm doing the right thing by modifying the user model directly.

Here's my controller. I set it to find the second user because I was simply testing it out to see if it worked.

```
class MeasurementsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @person = User.find(2)
    end
end
```

Here's my index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :style %>:
    <%= f.text_field :style %><br />
    <%= f.submit "Update"%>
<% end %>
```

However, it spits out this error:

```
NoMethodError in Measurements#index
undefined method `user_path'
```

Any help would be REALLY appreciated. Thanks so much in advance. Really lost here.

EDIT: Here's my routes.rb:

```
Contourfw::Application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  devise_for :users
  root :to => 'contourfw#landingpage'
  match "measurements" => "measurements#index"
  match "styles" => "styles#index"
end
```

Comment: To get this straight. You have users that signup and you would like them to be able to edit their profile/attributes after they are signed in?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. The thing is that I'm storing certain special properties, such as measurements, etc. with each user. I want the user to be able to change those properties once they've logged in.

Comment: why don't you create a link with Edit Profile then?

Comment: I want a separate page to change these special properties. The edit profile page is just for changing their password, etc.

Comment: it would be great if you could post your routes.rb file as well

Comment: Just posted it. Thanks!

Comment: A couple of things. Why in the measurements controller you have an index action? Shouldn't you have an edit action? Because if you do have an edit action then simply need an update action.

Comment: Something along these lines? http://chopapp.com/#y2nlnquh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add a resourceful route in your config/routes.rb:

```
resources :users
```

**Update**
By default that will assume a controller named users_controller.rb. If you want it to use the controller above, amend that to:

```
resources :users, :controller => "measurements"
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#customizing-resourceful-routes for more details.

Comment: hmm, doing that got the form to show up without my previous error, but attempting to submit the form gives me a 

    "Routing Error
    uninitialized constant UsersController"

Comment: I think doing this is conflicting with my devise installation. I already have `devise_for :users` in my routes.rb. this worked at first but then started causing a bunch of other problems.

Comment: In that case you probably want a 'resources :measurements' to point to your measurements controller, and in the view's form_for declaration, you'll need to add another parameter or to make the form submit to that controller instead of users_controller.